# json parsing without name in android

Tags: android, json

i have worked with json name value pair before works fine and great but below is my json object in which there is no name and only value. Can anyone tell is it possible to use this type of json in android if yes then how to extract values from this json object. or any related link will be great.

JSON OBJECT

```
{
    "log_list": [
        [
            "21",
            "doctorFisher",
            "Pharmacy 1",
            "patientfish",
            "test",
            "2014-08-25 05:58:18",
            "record UCI tech FDNY icky shut rack soon sun TDK tell. ox it'll ohm URL did GCVO dash ugly dog did flood idiot fluff if if rid t-shirts didn't TechTV only chef doc scotch Rebekah an if lb tax scotch am ICN JCB JCB HGV JCB HGV in on pm tax UDC OK red uh HK ohm",
            "<img id=\"prescription_image\" onClick=showPrescriptionDetails(\"3c59dc048e8850243be8079a5c74d079\") onmouseover=\"this.style.cursor='pointer'\" src=\"\" width=\"20\" height=\"20\">"
        ],
        [
            "20",
            "doctortest12345",
            "Pharmacy 1",
            "testpatient12345",
            "test",
            "2014-08-25 03:57:32",
            "she'd Urdu text scuff uno dad uno each ink why tough days ICO saved USCIS David rig though end FDIC UCI's for USCIS tend did for dog such vidi fly floor exited did DND hand bid GMD.",
            "<img id=\"prescription_image\" onClick=showPrescriptionDetails(\"98f13708210194c475687be6106a3b84\") onmouseover=\"this.style.cursor='pointer'\"  width=\"20\" height=\"20\">"
        ]
}
```

thanks in advance

Comment: They're called ‘arrays’. You can find out the rest yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that format would work and you can pretty easily use it.

Assuming you have a variable `String json` which contains that data:

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(json);
```

Now `log_list` would be parsed as a `JSONArray` like so:

```
JSONArray logJsonArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("log_list");
```

Then you can iterate through that outer array very similar to how you would a normal array or ArrayList:

```
for(int outerArrayPos = 0; outerArrayPos < logJsonArray.length(); outerArrayPos++){
    JSONArray innerArray = logJsonArray.getJSONArray(outerArrayPos);

    for(int innerArrayPos = 0; innerArrayPos < innerArray.length(); innerArrayPos++){
       String valueAtIndex = innerArray.getString(innerArrayPos); //innerArray

       // Do whatever you want with the values here
    }
}
```

That will parse your String, but figuring out how to actually use that data is going to be most of your struggle, so I hope the order in which the information is returned will always be the same for your sake.

If you can, I would definitely recommend using a JSONObject for the data that is currently contained in your inner array. e.g.

```
{
    "log_list": [
        {
            "id": "21",
            "name": "doctorFisher",
            .....
         }
     ]
 }
```